# React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> convert to String[]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-native, react-redux

```
onChange={(selected: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => handleOnChangeSelect(selected.target.value)}

const handleOnChangeSelect = (selected: String[]) => {
    setAccessSelected(selected.length > 0 && selected.some(product => product.includes(***)));
  };
```

How to convert from React.ChangeEvent to String[]?

I got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined when I try to transform string to array.

Comment: I am not sure your question makes much sense. Could you add more context, do you have an error? what are you trying to achieve? what is blocking you?

Comment: handleOnChangeSelect
This method gets String[], but when I use selected.target.value on React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> It's return string

Comment: you need to add more code to your question. for example the declaration of `handleOnChangeSelect `. If you have a typescript error as well add it to your question. It seems you want to transform a string to an array but without more information to exactly what is your problem, people are not gonna be able to help you.

Comment: My problem that I cannot transform string to array
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined